# Android BLE - Are custom threads started and finished from GattCallback methods eventually garbage collected?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a BLE Android app where I want to receive a notification that a variable has changed and then update a TextView.  UI components can only be updated on a UI thread, and the "OnCharacteristicChanged" method is inherently not a UI thread.  So the way I do it is as below in my GattCallback (where BLE_Test is the name of my main activity):

```
@Override
public void onCharacteristicChanged (BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic){

    //Get the value as a string from the characteristic, as well as the TextView I want to update

    Runnable t = new updateViews(viewToUpdate, updateString);
    BLE_Test.this.runOnUiThread(t);

}
```

Where I have this custom class in the main activity:

```
class updateViews implements Runnable {
    TextView viewToChange;
    String stringToSet;
    public updateViews(TextView viewToChange, String stringToSet) {
        this.viewToChange = viewToChange;
        this.stringToSet = stringToSet;
    }

    public void run() {
        viewToChange.setText(stringToSet);
    }
}
```

Now, I'm very conscious that with every call to "onCharacteristicChanged", I'm creating a new thread with new TextView and String parameters.  From my knowledge of Java, each "updateViews" thread should be garbage collected once the "onCharacteristicChanged" thread ends.  But is "onCharacteristicChanged" really a normal thread in that regard?  I just want to make sure that this method is thread safe and wont lead to memory leaks.  Also, if there's a better way of doing it, let me know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're good to go.

runOnUiThread does not start a new thread but schedules work to do on the main thread. Your objects will be garbage collected properly when there are no longer any references to them from any thread.